# `atinout` doesn't store the AT command response to a file

Tags: android, c, embedded-linux, at-command, modem

I'm trying to save the output of `atinout` to a file and I'm able to get the output on stdout. But not in a file, that is, my file is empty.

`atinout input.txt /dev/ttyUSB1 output.txt` is not working for me.

I think it's because my console doesn't come out of the command unless I press Ctrl + C. That is, my cursor stays blinking after `OK` till I press Ctrl + C.

```
$atinout input.txt /dev/ttyUSB1 -   
AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 27,99
OK

^C
```

For `AT`, it keeps on printing `AT` `OK` till I press Ctrl + C.

```
$echo AT | atinout - /dev/ttyUSB1 -
AAAT
OK

AAT
OK

AAT
OK

KAAT
OK

OAAT
OK

^C
```

What might be the issue? How can I save the `AT` command output to a file, instead of just displaying on stdout? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does something like `atinout input.txt > output.txt` work?

Comment: @0andriy: It works. But ```/dev/tty*``` has to be given. I think it's because my console doesn't come out at ```cat``` side even if i do something like -- 

```echo -e "AT\r" > /dev/ttyUSB1``` and ```cat /dev/ttyUSB1``` on other terminal. I get the same output as shown in the question above and console doesn't come out at ```cat``` terminal. Anyways, i wrote a ```C``` code using termios and i'm using that.

Answer (score 1):

atinout's ability to work with URCs is a bit limited. It will only return +CME ERROR and +CMS ERROR codes.

You will need to edit the source code and change "+" case like this:

```
switch (response[0]) {
case '+':
    if (STARTS_WITH(&response[1], "CME ERROR:")) {
        return true;
    }
    if (STARTS_WITH(&response[1], "CMS ERROR:")) {
        return true;
    }
    //Add CSQ URC
    if (STARTS_WITH(&response[1], "CSQ:")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

However if the OK response comes before the URC, then that will be output instead.